# Can I add a column and index it at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I ran the following migration:

```
rails generate migration add_username_to_users username:string
```

And then I tried two ways to add uniqueness to it:

```
class AddUsernameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :username, :string, :unique => true
  end
  # or add_index :users, :username, :unique => true
end
```

But this didn't work for me. I know I could run another migration to add the index but I wanted to know if it's possible to index when you add the column? This way I can keep the amount of migrations to a minimum.

Comment: Mu's already answered, but for future reference, when things don't work, it's helpful to include what the symptoms of "not working" are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `:unique` option for [`add_column`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_column) so the `:unique => true` on

```
add_column :users, :username, :string, :unique => true
```

is ignored. You can do two things at once in a single migration though so just add your `add_index` to your AddUsernameToUsers migration:

```
class AddUsernameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :username, :string, :unique => true
    add_index :users, :username, :unique => true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `change_table` method, like so

```
class AddUsernameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table(:users) do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.index :username, :unique => true
    end
  end
end
```

The advantage of using `change_table` is that for mysql you can pass `:bulk => true` which generates a single `ALTER TABLE` sql statement and is thus much quicker for large tables (since mysql effectively copies the entire table every time you do an alter table)